# I am returning a count from a column in a dataframe successfully, but I get NaN value when trying to import results into a column

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, pandas-groupby, jupyter, arcgis

I am new to ArcGIS API for Python and I am trying to create a tool using Notebook in ArcGIS Pro 10.5, that will re-engineer a table (csv file). The dataframe is titled **data_df** I need to get a count of the amount of ages, per country, that occured in a particular age group (Under 1, 1-2yrs, 3-4yrs, 5-12yrs, 13-17yrs, 18 & older). A sample of my data is set up as follows:

#### Country Age Gender

USA  3 M 
USA 5 F 
USA 10 M F 
Canada 0 M 
Canada 1 M 
Canada 9 F 
Mexico 13 M 
Mexico 18 F

I created a python snippet that will give me the count and sum that I am looking for. This example gives me the count for the 1-2yrs group, and it works!

`data_df.loc[(data_df['Age'] >=1) & (data_df['Age'] <=2)].groupby('Country')['Age'].count()`

The problem is that I am trying to create new columns that will give me the totals, per country. I know there are duplicates and I can delete those later. I have tried the code below:

`data_df['Hague1_2'] = data_df.loc[(data_df['Age'] >=1) & (data_df['Age'] <=2)].groupby('Country')['Age'].count()`

The result should look like the following but instead I get NaN values:

#### Country Age Gender Under1 Yr1-2 Yr3-4 Yr5-12 Yr13-17 Yr18Older

USA  3 M 0 0 1 2 0 0
USA 5 F 0 0 1 2 0 0
USA 10 M F 0 0 1 2 0 0
Canada 0 M 1 1 0 1 0 0
Canada 1 M 0 M 1 1 0 1 0 0
Canada 9 F 0 M 1 1 0 1 0 0
Mexico 13 M 0 0 0 0 1 1
Mexico 18 F 0 0 0 0 1 1

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a dictionary, which you can use to remap your values. Then use one-hot encoding.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([ ['USA', 3, 'M'], ['USA', 5, 'F'], ['USA', 10, 'F'], 
                    ['Canada', 0, 'M'],['Canada', 1, 'M'], ['Canada', 9, 'F'], 
                    ['Mexico', 13, 'M'],['Mexico', 18, 'F']], columns = ['Country', 'Age', 'Gender'])

remap_dct = { 0: "Under 1",
             1: "1-2yrs",
             2: "1-2yrs",
             3: "3-4yrs",
             4: "3-4yrs",
             5: "5-12yrs",
             6: "5-12yrs",
             7: "5-12yrs",
             8: "5-12yrs",
             9: "5-12yrs",
             10: "5-12yrs",
             11: "5-12yrs",
             12: "5-12yrs",
             13: "13-17yrs",
             14: "13-17yrs",
             15: "13-17yrs",
             16: "13-17yrs",
             17: "13-17yrs"}

df['AgeGroup'] = df['Age'].map(remap_dct)
df.loc[df['Age'] >= 18, 'AgeGroup'] = "18 & older"
df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['AgeGroup']))
df = df.drop('AgeGroup', axis=1)
print(df)

  Country  Age Gender  1-2yrs  13-17yrs  18 & older  3-4yrs  5-12yrs  Under 1
0     USA    3      M       0         0           0       1        0        0
1     USA    5      F       0         0           0       0        1        0
2     USA   10      F       0         0           0       0        1        0
3  Canada    0      M       0         0           0       0        0        1
4  Canada    1      M       1         0           0       0        0        0
5  Canada    9      F       0         0           0       0        1        0
6  Mexico   13      M       0         1           0       0        0        0
7  Mexico   18      F       0         0           1       0        0        0
```